# PhoneGap MediaFile.lastModifiedDate to Javascript Date

Tags: javascript, cordova

According to the PhoneGap [documentation](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.8.0/cordova_media_capture_capture.md.html#MediaFile), the MediaFile.lastModifiedDate property is a Date object. But when I look at the value, all I see is a really long integer (ex: 1370969061000). I assume this is some kind of UTC time, but I am having difficulty converting this to a standard Javascript Date object type, so that I can extract the date and time components individually. I haven't had much luck searching online, so I thought I'd ask on here if anyone has accomplished this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you *actually* have a number, pass the number directly into the `Date` constructor:

```
> new Date(1370969061000)
Tue Jun 11 2013 12:44:21 GMT-0400
```

From MDN's page on [JavaScript's `Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date):

> `new Date(value)`
>
> **value**: Integer value representing the number of milliseconds since 1 January 1970 00:00:00 UTC (Unix Epoch).

However, the PhoneGap docs say that `lastModifiedDate` should be a `Date` object already. You might be doing some math that coerces the `Date` object into a number, in which case it turns into a timestamp value:

```
> 1 + new Date(1370969061000)
1370969061001
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you! Also, I am not modifying the lastModifiedDate property in any way, the property simply seems to be an integer, not a Date.